# Is there a deduction query?

Tags: sql-server

Is there any way to deduct certain value without knowing its original value in update query?

Comment: How about `item_quanttity - 5`?

Answer (score 3):

Egads. The operator is still a minus sign (`-`). So:

```
UPDATE Item SET item_quantity = item_quantity - 5 WHERE ID = 1;
```

In SQL Server 2008 and above, new shorthand is supported:

```
UPDATE Item SET item_quantity -= 5 WHERE ID = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Ya, the built-in command is called `-`:

```
SELECT item_quantity - 5 FROM item WHERE ID = 1
```